# Why does $1 point to the same value with several regex matches in a hashref assignment?

Tags: regex, perl

For just the problem without a story, skip to after the line.

I was fooling around with splitting up a string of some letters and numbers, both of which could occur, into two fields in a hashref. They should only appear if the field exists at all. The string might look like this: `/^\D*\d*$/`, for example `ZR17`, `R15`, `-19`, `22`.

I did not want to simply put this into two variables like this, because the actual hashref is a little longer, and I wanted to keep stuff grouped together.

```
my $asdf = "ZR17";
my ($x, $y) = $asdf =~ m/^(\D*)(\d*)$/;
my $foo = {
  foo => $x,
  bar => $y
};
```

If I wanted to not have the key `foo` in case of the string `17`, I could say:

```
my $foo = {
  ( $x ? ( foo => $x ) : () ),
  ( $y ? ( bar => $y ) : () ),
};
```

---

I came up with putting it all in the hashref assignment like this:

```
my $asdf = "ZR17";

my $foo = {
  ( $asdf =~ m/(\d+)/ ? ( foo => $1 ) : () ),
  ( $asdf =~ m/(\D+)/ ? ( bar => $1 ) : () ),
};

print Dumper $foo;
```

This yields the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bar' => 'ZR',
          'foo' => 'ZR'
        };
```

Somehow it looks like there is only one `$1` here, and it gets mixed up. If I coment out the second line, `foo` will be `17`.

Can someone explain what is happening here? **Where is the `$1` getting lost/confused?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to perldoc (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

```
These special variables, like ... the numbered match variables ($1 , $2 , $3 
, etc.) are dynamically scoped until the end of the enclosing block or until 
the next successful match, whichever comes first.
```

Therefore, $1 has been overwritten to 17 after $asdf =~ m/(\d+)/ as it found a match but hasn't encountered the end of the enclosing block yet.

This however,

```
my $foo = {
  ( eval{$asdf =~ m/(\D+)/ ? ( bar => $1 ) : ()} ),
  ( eval{$asdf =~ m/(\d+)/ ? ( foo => $1 ) : ()} ),
};
```

will give the expected result as the scopes are separated.

Comment: I was looking for that part of the perldoc, but did not see it. Thanks a lot. Very good answer by the way. I did not accept it because I think the `map` solution is better/more efficient.

Comment: That's fine, I wasn't trying to give a solution either, just to show where the problem is as that's what was asked:)

Comment: You're right. That's what I asked. You do deserve the accept after all. :)

Answer (score 4):

Perl 5.10+ will allow you to use [named captures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences), which is essentially what you want to do. Any capture group that doesn't match will be stored in [`%+`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) with `""` as the value in your case:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump 'dd';

my $asdf = "ZR17";
$asdf =~ m/^(?<alpha>\D*)(?<num>\d*)$/;

my $foo = { map { $+{$_} ? ( $_ => $+{$_} ) : () } keys %+ };

dd $foo;  # { alpha => "ZR", num => 17 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `$1` for `foo` and `bar` is from last regex match,

```
my $asdf = "ZR17";

my $foo = {
  ( $asdf =~ m/(\D+)/ ? ( bar => $1 ) : () ),
  ( $asdf =~ m/(\d+)/ ? ( foo => $1 ) : () ),
};

print Dumper $foo;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'bar' => '17',
      'foo' => '17'
    };
```

This however works as expected,

```
my $foo = {
  ( map { (bar => $_) } $asdf =~ m/(\D+)/ ),
  ( map { (foo => $_) } $asdf =~ m/(\d+)/ ),
};
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'bar' => 'ZR',
      'foo' => '17'
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the ternary operator doesn't evaluate `$1` when it returns `( bar => $1 )` and `( foo => $1 )`. So in the intermediary step you get

```
$foo = { ( bar => $1 ), ( foo => $1 ) };
```

And since `$1` is by now the captured substring of 2nd match operation, you get the same values for both `$foo{bar}` and `$foo{foo}`.

---

Another way to achieve what you want (i.e. the hash element doesn't exist if corresponding match is not found):

```
my %patt = {
    foo => '(\d+)',
    bar => '(\D+)',
};

my %foo = map { $_ => $1 if $asdf =~ /$patt{$_}/ } keys %patt;
```

You can extend `%patt` when you need to match more patterns.