# What is the meaning of "keys %+"?

Tags: perl

What does this code mean?

```
keys %+
```

I saw it in some source code, and I don't know what Perl documentation to read to find out what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash `%+` has all the matches from named capture groups in regexes in the current scope. It's explained in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) under `%LAST_PAREN_MATCH` and was added in 5.10.

> Similar to @+ , the %+ hash allows access to the named capture
>   buffers, should they exist, in the last successful match in the
>   currently active dynamic scope. [..]

The [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function lists all the keys in the hash.

Comment: Also, I learned that only today from @Zaid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16897774/1331451

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this feature was added in Perl 5.10 (yes, some people are actually stuck with Perl 5.8 or earlier).

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you see a groovy-looking variable, look it up in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

In this case, `%+` is the hash that stores the values corresponding to the named captures of the last regex:

> Similar to `@+` , the `%+` hash allows access to the named capture
>   buffers, should they exist, in the last successful match in the
>   currently active dynamic scope. For example, `$+{foo}` is equivalent to
>   `$1` after the following match:
>
> ```
> 'foo' =~ /(?<foo>foo)/;
> ```

See [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

These docs are what you want:

`perldoc -f keys`

`perldoc -v %+`

Comment: That behavior for `perldoc -v` requires the perldoc from perl 5.12 or newer. In older version it would give verbose information about its search for the requested docs, which is now the `-D` option.